# leaflet - marker cluster: popup doesnt work on the cluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, markerclusterer

I tried to use the leaflet marker cluster. I have a popup bind to each marker. If I want to have the popup works, then my map will look like this:

[image: cluster and popup]

The code :

```
   var popup = "popup test";
   map.addLayer(marker);

   markers[marker._leaflet_id] = marker;
   marker.bindPopup(popup);
   clusterMarkers.addLayer(marker);
   map.addLayer(clusterMarkers);
```

But if I want the cluster works nice and neat (by delete the map.addLayer(marker) from the previous code), then the popup doesn't work on my map when I try to click onto the marker. 
[image: popup problem]

The code :

```
   var popup = "popup test";
   //map.addLayer(marker);

   markers[marker._leaflet_id] = marker;
   marker.bindPopup(popup);
   clusterMarkers.addLayer(marker);
   map.addLayer(clusterMarkers);
```

I am wondering how can I have nice and neat marker cluster as figure 1 but my popup still working as figure 2 on each marker?

Comment: I am not sure we can tell without seeing an example. Like this http://plnkr.co/edit/AuakADHXboI18S81ADjG?p=preview

Comment: @FranceImage , I am trying to reproduce what I am trying to do using your example codes. http://plnkr.co/edit/SBHbykiVaxw8a7UEgNII you can check that link. I am trying to put a sidebar which associate for each marker. It should be autoscrolled when user choose the marker. If user chooses the item on the sidebar, the cluster should be exposed. I dont think I get it right, the markers / cluster and sidebar doesnt show up.

Comment: And what should happen if the item of the sidebar you click has its marker clustered ?

Comment: @FranceImage The marker should show up, popup is auto-open, and unspidered under clustered. I am not sure if I make it right. It just shows up a blank map http://plnkr.co/edit/SBHbykiVaxw8a7UEgNII?p=preview on this

Comment: marker._leaflet_id gives me undefined without having map.addLayer(marker) onto cluster markers. @FranceImage

Comment: yes, _leaflet_id is private. Just add your own id to each marker.

Comment: I think I figure it out by doing map.addLayer(marker), and then map.removeLayer(marker) after markers[marker._leaflet_id] = marker